# Windows registry database parsing

Tags: windows, google-chrome, registry, kaitai-struct

I'm trying to parse Windows registry database hives file format using [Kaitai Web IDE](http://kt.pe/kaitai_struct_webide/) using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364281/windows-registry-hive-files-documentation) as a reference, but I ran into the problem. The hive I'm most interested in is `c:\windows\system32\config\software`, and it's more than 90 MB.

When I'm trying to load it up in the Kaitai Web IDE, I get only first 0x97d680 bytes loaded. It looks like everything else is truncated.

My first guess is that probably it's some sort of browser limitation. 0x97d680 bytes is 9950848 in decimal. Indeed, after some googling I find that there is 10 MB limit on something called "local storage" in modern browsers.

I'm using Google Chrome 56.0.2924.9 on Windows 10. Any ideas what can I try to alleviate this limitation?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is actually a limitation of the WebIDE, more precisely the hex viewer's scrollbar which limits how long you can scroll down, so I have to replace it with a virtual scrollbar implementation.

If you view the contents of the local storage (which is actually stored in the indexedDB) then you will probably see that the whole file is stored:

[image: how to view the stored file size]

If the free space is not enough when you upload a file then your browser should ask for more space I think.

As a long-term solution for bigger files we are planning to wrap the WebIDE into desktop clients with direct file system access, but this is a low priority item on our list so probably won't happen in the near future.

I will fix the issue during the weekend and I will update this answer.

If you'd like to get faster updates you can visit us in our [Gitter chatroom](https://gitter.im/kaitai_struct/Lobby).

**Update**

I created a workaround for the issue: I kept the original implementation for now, but made it possible to load bigger files, but it has a side-effect for big files (>16MB): scrolling with mouse scrolls much more than before. Please use Page+Up/Down if you want to scroll only a page.